Gini coefficient in hive by group
I have a table with three columns group, person, score I would like to calculate the Gini coefficient for score per group. So that I can measure the inequality of persons based on score What is the most efficient way to do this?

Here is Gini coefficient calculation ( with random sample data ) done with Oracle SQL code:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    balances AS 
        ( Select DATE '2018-01-01' as A_DATE, IN_VAL as BALANCE
          From    ( Select 11 as IN_VAL From Dual Union All
                    Select 12 From Dual Union All
                    Select 13 From Dual Union All
                    Select 14 From Dual Union All
                    Select 15 From Dual )  -- Gini: 0.061538   [11,12,13,14,15]
        Union All
          Select DATE '2018-01-02' as A_DATE, IN_VAL as BALANCE
          From    ( Select 33 as IN_VAL From Dual Union All
                    Select 33 From Dual Union All
                    Select 33 From Dual Union All
                    Select 33 From Dual )  -- Gini: 0.0  [33,33,33,33]
        Union All
          Select DATE '2018-01-03' as A_DATE, IN_VAL as BALANCE
          From    ( Select 142 as IN_VAL From Dual Union All
                    Select 152 From Dual Union All
                    Select 112 From Dual Union All
                    Select 182 From Dual Union All
                    Select 162 From Dual Union All
                    Select 1452 From Dual Union All
                    Select 1672 From Dual Union All
                    Select 112 From Dual Union All
                    Select 142 From Dual Union All
                    Select 1112 From Dual)  -- Gini: 0.541985  [142,152,112,182,162,1452,1672,112,142,112]
        ),

With CTE ranked_balances - Rank the data from bigest to smallest
    ranked_balances AS 
        ( Select A_DATE, BALANCE, 
                 Row_Number() Over(Partition By A_DATE Order By BALANCE Desc) as RANK
          From balances
        ) 

--    M a i n    S Q L :    ( Gini Calculation )
SELECT      A_DATE, 
        -- (1 − 2B) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient
            Round( 1 - ( 2 * 
                         Sum( (BALANCE * (RANK - 1) + BALANCE / 2) ) / 
                         Count(*) / 
                         sum(BALANCE)
                       ), 6 
                 ) as GINI
FROM        ranked_balances
GROUP BY    A_DATE
HAVING      Sum(BALANCE) > 0
ORDER BY    A_DATE 

/*    R e s u l t :
A_DATE         GINI
-------- ----------
01.01.18   0.061538   
02.01.18          0
03.01.18   0.541985      */

Results could be checked Here
